# How to get specific value from parent-class in django serializer

Tags: django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-views

**Context**

I am trying to recreate the hospital management system wherein once the user logins[either as a patient or as a doctor] on the website; the patient/user can track their health record and so can the concerned doctor.
To do so, I have used the AbstractBaseUser class to create a custom-user-model wherein user can choose their user-role which is either doctor or patient during signup

```
class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """ Database Model for users in the system """
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('DOCTOR', 'DOCTOR'),
        ('PATIENT', 'PATIENT'),
    )
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                                 choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES, null=True)
```

The doctor model is an extension of UserProfile model with doc as ForeignKey attribute

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    doc = models.ForeignKey(
        UserProfile, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #.....Other doctor attributes.....

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.doc.name}'
```

The patient model is an extension of both UserProfile and Doctor

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    pat = models.ForeignKey(
        UserProfile, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(
        Doctor, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.pat.name}'
```

The disease of the patient is another model which is has a foreign-key attribute patient

```
class DiseaseOfPatient(models.Model):
    pat = models.ForeignKey(Patient,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #other attributes are ailment attributes of that particular patient
```

**Problem**
When I run "python manage.py shell" and inside it, I query

```
doc1 = Doctor.objects.get(id=1)
doc1.patient_set.all()
--> <QuerySet [<Patient: Naruto Uzumaki>, <Patient: Sasuke Uchiha>]>
*I need this in my serializer as well*
```

When I did this in my ListAPIView
wherein I define the get_queryset()
and write the same logic ie

```
def get_queryset(self):
        doctor_query= models.Doctor.objects.filter(
            doc=self.request.user.id)
        queryset = doctor_query.patient_set.all()#to get each patient from that doctor
        return queryset
```

, But I am using ForiegnKey attribute instead of names I get their "id"

```
*The output I get*
[
    {
        "doc": 1,
        "pat": 1,
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "doc": 1,
        "pat": 2,
        "id": 1
    }
]
*The output I expect*
[
    {
        "doc": "Sakura Haruno",
        "pat": [
                {
                  "name": "Sasuke Uchiha",
                   "id":2 #--> This is "id" field of "Patient" model
                }
                {
                  "name": "Naruto Uzumaki",
                   "id":1 #--> This is "id" field of "Patient" model
                }
               ]
        "id":1 #--> This is "id" field of "Doctor" model
        
    }
]
```

I thought of using HyperlinkedIdentityField but it creates a URL that I don't want.
I cannot find a suitable serializer_relation which could fulfill this

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good you realize you haven't got the right model relations. You basically have a User (it's a user, don't call it UserProfile, that's something else) and two specialized versions of it. Specialization is done through inheritance, not foreign keys.
The [documentation is very elaborate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance):

> There are three styles of inheritance that are possible in Django.
>
> Often, you will just want to use the parent class to hold information that you don’t want to have to type out for each child model. This class isn’t going to ever be used in isolation, so Abstract base classes are what you’re after.
>
> If you’re subclassing an existing model (perhaps something from another application entirely) and want each model to have its own database table, Multi-table inheritance is the way to go.
>
> Finally, if you only want to modify the Python-level behavior of a model, without changing the models fields in any way, you can use Proxy models.

I suggest you read this carefully, while you can still change your models. Things are only going to get more complicated if you stick to your current data model.

---

Update: data model for patient/doctors/ailment/care

Here's an example of how I could structure the models. It uses both abstract base classes and multi-table inheritance and allows for patients, doctors and ailments all to have multiple relations with each other.
It also gives a hint on how you could automatically select doctors for a given ailment, through the definition of specialities.

These are examples you can use as a guide.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.utils import timezone


class NamedModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def create_user(self, email, name, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", False)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", False)
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, name=name, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, name, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.update(is_superuser=True, is_staff=True)
        return self.create_user(email, name, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    """
    Custom User:

    - Login via Email, remove username field
    - Removed first_name and last_name field
    - Made email unique as it is username
    - Added name field and made it required

    Usage in settings.py: AUTH_USER_MODEL = '<appname>.User'
    """

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["name"]
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = ""
    last_name = ""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    objects = UserManager()

    @property
    def is_doctor(self):
        return hasattr(self, "doctor")

    @property
    def is_patient(self):
        return hasattr(self, "patient")


class Specialty(NamedModel):
    pass


class Doctor(User):
    specialty = models.ForeignKey(
        Specialty, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="physicians"
    )

    @property
    def is_doctor(self):
        return True

    @property
    def is_patient(self):
        return False


class Ailment(NamedModel):
    treatment_specialty = models.ForeignKey(
        Specialty, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="ailments"
    )


class Care(models.Model):
    physician = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    patient = models.ForeignKey("Patient", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    ailment = models.ForeignKey(Ailment, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    start_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    ended_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    primary_physician = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def is_active(self):
        return self.ended_at is None


class Patient(User):
    physicians = models.ManyToManyField(Doctor, related_name="patients", through=Care)

    @property
    def is_doctor(self):
        return True

    @property
    def is_patient(self):
        return True

    def active_care(self):
        return Care.objects.filter(patient=self, ended_at__isnull=True)

    def start_treatment(self, doc_name="Doctor John", disease="Flu", starting=None):
        physician = Doctor.objects.get(name__iexact=doc_name)
        ailment = Ailment.objects.get(name__iexact=disease)
        return Care.objects.create(
            physician=physician, patient=self, ailment=ailment, start_at=starting
        )

    def end_treatment(self, doc_name="Doctor John", disease="Flu"):
        physician = Doctor.objects.get(name__iexact=doc_name)
        ailment = Ailment.objects.get(name__iexact=disease)
        care = Care.objects.get(
            physician=physician, ailment=ailment, patient=self, ended_at__isnull=True
        )
        care.ended_at = timezone.now()
        care.save(update_fields=["ended_at"])
        return care
```

Examples of how to use them:

```
In [3]: doc = models.Doctor.objects.get(name='Doctor John')                                                                                                                                                 

In [4]: doc.patients                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[4]: <django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward_many_to_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager at 0x11176ca00>

In [5]: doc.patients.all()                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[5]: <QuerySet [<Patient: john@doe.example.com>]>

In [6]: patient = models.Patient.objects.get(name='John Doe')                                                                                                                                               

In [7]: patient.physicians                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[7]: <django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward_many_to_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager at 0x1117c24f0>

In [8]: patient.physicians.all()                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[8]: <QuerySet [<Doctor: yoohan@cha.example.com>]>

In [16]: print(' - '.join([care.physician.name, care.patient.name, care.ailment.name, str(care.start_at)]))                                                                                                 
Doctor John - John Doe - Flu - 2020-07-25 21:12:58.953093+00:00
```

Comment: Sir, I will certainly make the changes, but I don't know how should I create the model-relation for Patient--Doctor--Patient_Ailment so that queryset would be easy.
I really could use your help

Comment: Thank you so much @Melvyn will do the changes in my code.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple changes needed here.

```
queryset = doctor_query.patient_set.all()
```

This will return a row for every patient. Naturally when this is serialized this will lead to multiple rows. You can't fix this from within the get_queryset() function

Instead what you should do is add a field in the serializer:

```
user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
```

and a function

```
def get_user():
    # Get Doctor ID
    # Get all patients
    # Use PatientSerializer to serialize all patients and return an array of arrays of their serialization
```

Comment: Also there are a bunch more suggestions for you: Instead of using a ForeignKey to map to the UserProfile, you should really be using a OneToOne key. And is there a specific reason why you are allowing Doctors to have their UserProfile reference as None?

Comment: I actually had oneToOne Field and I had to change it as I was working with serializer-relation wherein to use HyperlinkedIdentityField but will take your suggestion @Aayush Agarwal

Answer (score 0):

So the workaround I found was good enough but the thing is I haven't created proper model-relations but I, fortunately, scavenged my way to the desired solution.

```
def get_patient_set_name(self, obj):
        ''' <obj> refers to the object of Doctor-Model '''
        print("patient->>>>>>>>>>>>", str(obj.patient_set.all())
              )  # give the list of patient pertaining to the doctor
        pat_list = []
        for patient in obj.patient_set.all():
            """ <patient> is an object of the doctor whose
                object has been send into the function
            """
            x = patient
            y = patient.pat.name
            print(patient)
            print("====================", type(x)) # returns --> <class 'sepsisAPI.models.Patient'>
            print("====================", type(y)) # returns --> str
            print("NAME IS>>>>>>>>>>>>>", y)
            pat_list.append(y)  # pat_list += patient

        print(pat_list)
        return pat_list  # str(obj)
```

**The Output**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "doc_name": "Tsunade Senju",
        "patient_set": [
            1,
            2
        ],
        "patient_set_name": [
            "Naruto Uzumaki",
            "Sasuke Uchiha"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "doc_name": "Sakura Haruno",
        "patient_set": [],
        "patient_set_name": []
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "doc_name": "Shizune",
        "patient_set": [],
        "patient_set_name": []
    }
]
```